# How many unique combinations of 2 letters from a word?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Let's say that I have the word CANE.
How many unique groups of two letters can I create without considering the order of the letters?
In this case I can easily calculate the answer (6) using the binomial coefficient 4 over 2.

But what if the word is CANA? Cleary now the answer is 4 (CA, CN, AN, AA), but which mathematical formula should I use to take into consideration the fact that two letters are equal?

Thanks

Comment: You could imagine that you had two different As to begin with, say $A_1$ and $A_2$, use your old formula, and then work out how to correct for the fact that you have two letters the same

Answer (score 1):

There are $3$ distinct letters plus one repeat, and order is not important,

so choose $2$ from $3$ distinct letters + choose $2$ from $2$ identical ones

= $\binom32 +\binom22 = 4$